# Installing Java from PPA in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, repository, packages, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Java on Ubuntu 12.04 but facing some problems doing it from the command line.

When I tried to add the repository using this command, I get errors:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/java
Traceback (most recent call last):                 
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 125, in <module>             
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)             
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in          get_ppa_info_from_lp                                  
    curl.perform()                                      
pycurl.error: (6, "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'")
```

Comment: with Java you mean what ?

Comment: @H2CO3 http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: i mean jdk package

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/89098

Comment: "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'" This error seems pretty self-explanatory.. Can you resolve, ping and connect to that hostname?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a gui login then you can try this, under **System Settings > Software Sources > Other Software**

Click on **Add...** and paste **ppa:flexiondotorg/java**

You will find that two new entries are now part of the repo list.
Now you can go ahead and do an apt-get update followed by apt-get install.